# Powershell separates suffix from last name

Tags: powershell-3.0

I will have a list of names in a text file:
ex:
Smith III
Johnson JR.
Lee

I need to separate the suffix from the last name.  The suffix will be determined if the name contains a space, and if to the right of that space there is text with less then 4 characters, or else it will be considered part of the normal name.  I will then need to output the data into a csv file containing three columns; original, last name, suffix.

Any suggestions?

```
$InputLocation = "C:\test\suffix test\"
$OutputLocation = "C:\test\suffix test\"

$file = gci -Path $InputLocation

$lines = Get-Content($file.FullName)|

Foreach-object{

    $pattern = "(.*)( )(.*)"
    Write-Host $Matches[3]
    if($_ -match $pattern -and $Matches[3] -lt 4){

        $a = $Matches[0]
        $b = $Matches[1]
        $c = $Matches[3]


        $output = $a + "," + $b + "," + $c
        $output

    }else{ 


       $e = $_
       $outputElse = $e + "," + $e
       $outputElse

    }

    }| Set-Content($OutputLocation + "Output.csv")
```

This is where i am at. this will work almost perfectly except for in one instance where JR is not taken as a suffix

```
Input file is a text file that looks similar to 
Johnson
Smith Jr
Manca III
Clarke
Champagne
Manship (T)


Expected Output would be
Johnson|Johnson|<null>
Smith Jr.|Smith|Jr 
Manca III|Manca|III
Clarke|Clarke|<null>
Champagne|Champagne|<null>
Manship (T)|Manship|(T)
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what your rules for the name is. I'm guessing you want the example you provided to be interpreted as surname: "Smith III Johnson", suffix: "JR.", given name: "Lee", is that right? Could you please provide further details on the rules for the name format and also several more examples with expected output for each name?

Comment: I updated the script above.  I need a csv file. column 1: original name, ex: johnson III.  column 2: Johnson Column 3: III

Comment: The above newer script shoots out one mistake where it doesn't pick up jr in the last name.  the script is supposed to find the space and accept anything to the right of the space that is less than 4 characters long as a suffix

Comment: Could you please create a list with several examples and expected output for each example? It would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: above i added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function would do the parsing you're looking for. It succeeds on the teststrings you've provided.

```
function Split-NameString
{
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
    PROCESS 
    {
        $trimmedName = $Name.Trim()
        $trimmedName -match "^(?<surname>.*?)(?:| (?<suffix>[^ ]{1,3}))$" | Out-Null
        Write-Output (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            FullName = $trimmedName;
            Surname = $Matches["surname"];
            Suffix = $Matches["suffix"];
        })
    }
}
```

What you could then do, to read the strings from a file and write the output to a csv-file, is something like the following:

```
$names = Get-Content "c:\input.txt"
$names | Split-NameString | Select FullName, Surname, Suffix | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\output.csv"
```

The `Select FullName, Surname, Suffix` part is to get the columns in the order you like in the csv file.

Comment: This does work.  thank you very much, this is great.  

However, mine worked on every single case but one so it worked for 144 of 145 of suffixes.  do you have any thoughts as to why mine didn't work for all of them?

Comment: Miller JR------this was also the only JR in the file.  the rest were 2nd, 3rd, (t) which all worked

Comment: When I read your script again, I can see that you're doing <code>$Matches[3] -lt 4</code> which isn't right. You should be doing <code>$Matches[3].Length -lt 4</code>. That might be your issue.